# Extract decibels from short array, derived from byte array coming from Android AudioRecord

Tags: android, audio, audiorecord, decibel

I want to get the average decibels over a period of time (lets say 1 second). **Edit**: This is to detect loud noises.

I have a ByteArray of audio, at 16khz sample rate and 16 bit depth.

I convert it to a ShortArray to get the amplitude of over time, like so:

```
fun bytesToShort(byteArray: ByteArray): ShortArray {
    val shortOut = ShortArray(byteArray.size / 2)
    val byteBuffer: ByteBuffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(byteArray)
    byteBuffer.order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN).asShortBuffer().get(shortOut)
    return shortOut
}
```

From what I gather, this is the correct way to get the amplitude.

Now my converting algorithm:

```
val amplitudeValues = bytesToShort(bytesForDecibels)
val rms = sqrt(amplitudeValues.sumOf { it * it } / amplitudeValues.size.toDouble())
val decibels = 20 * log10(rms)
```

It spits out apparent decibel values. However, I tried a recording where I literally scream in the microphone, and can't reach an average of over 51 decibels. Is my algorithm correct and the microphone simply cannot pick up louder sounds then 51db, or is the algorithm incomplete/incorrect?

**Edit**: I didn't mention I wanted to detect loud noises. Reading from @GabeSechan's comment, I need to check amplitude spikes over a baseline amplitude to detect a loud noise. So I will set a baseline according to microphone activity and any large spikes over baselines are loud noises.

Comment: Where did you get that formula?  Decibels aren't measured like that.  The formula for decibels is 10*log_10(I/I_0). where I is the intensity of the sound, and I_0 is baseline intensity required to hear anything.  You might use RMS over a series of points to find an average intensity, but I'm not sure where 20 came from, and I don't see a baseline in your algorithm, unless you're asssuming the baseline is 1.

Comment: @GabeSechan thanks for the comment, as far as defining a baseline, I guess it varies according to the hardware and microphone specs on the phone?

Also, I simply want to detect loud noises. Would using the amplitude be a better and more precise measurement? Thanks

Comment: If you just want to detect loud noises, amplitude (or possibly abs(amplitude)) is sufficient.  Define a threshold and look for values above that threshold.